# Github action ignores all environment variables defined in a bash.sh script

Tags: github-actions

I have a bash script that sets a series of environment variables.

My action includes the following two steps:

```
  - name: Set env variables
    run: source ./setvars.sh

  - name: dump env variables
    run: env
```

I notice setvars.sh runs successfully, but all of the variables defined inside it are missing after the steps.

How can I use a bash .sh script to add environment variables to the context of the workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see environment variables defined by sourcing file in GitHub Actions workflow.

I only see them defined as [map (key-value) at the job or workflow level](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables) (since [oct. 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-01-github-actions-new-workflow-syntax-features/#env-at-the-workflow-and-job-level)).

See if you can cat your file and [append its content to `GITHUB_ENV`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable).

Comment: Thanks for help. When I am setting 30 environment variables in a bash.sh files, are suggesting the bash.sh script write them to a text file every line is like var1=value1. How do I assign all variables in the text file to $GITHUB_ENV?

Comment: @AllanXu your script should read the file line by line, and echo each line to GITHUB_ENV (as shown in the second link)